# swift determine if a certain row disappear from view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've have been sniffing around to find the solution but up until now its fruitless. What I want to do is to determine if a certain cell disappeared from screen.

Here's the code i have been trying:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let indexPathWatchCell = NSIndexPath(forRow: 4, inSection: 0)

    if ((tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.contains(indexPathWatchCell)) == nil){
        NSLog("it disappeared!!")
    }
}
```

Unfortunately its not working, any ideas?

EDIT:

for clarity, what I want to accomplish is set the size of the cell to CGFLOAT(44) when it disappeared in view

Comment: This method works when cell was removed from the table

Comment: ohh. Oddly when i use !=nil the NSLog appeared, Interesting. Any idea to determine if the cell disappeared from view?

Comment: Try use UITableViewCell prepareForReuse(): since cells get reused when they are not visible. Also remember that table views hold two cells off the viewing frame for performance reasons (one on top and one on bottom).

Comment: Have you tried to print out the indexPath ? This should give you a hint, what to put in your indexPathWatchCell. Additionally your code searches thru all visible cells but gets the one cell, that disappeared as parameter to the function. Is there a special reason or could you improve by directly comparing the parameter?

Comment: @hershalle got it, thanks.

Comment: @jboi yeah i figured it out that I do not need to put it on didEndDisplayingCell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`contains` method return Boolean value if the object contains other wise return false, so you need to check for that not for `nil` so change your code like this.

```
if (tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.contains(indexPathWatchCell)){
    NSLog("it not disappeared!!")
}
else {
    NSLog("it's disappeared!!")
}
```

Or if you just want to know for "disappeared" than you can use `!`(not) with `if`

```
if (!tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.contains(indexPathWatchCell)){
    NSLog("it disappeared!!")
}
```

Comment: can i change the height of the a certain cell if it disappeared in view?

Comment: If that cell is disappeared, than what reason to change the height of that cell, because it is currently not visible on screen.

Comment: the thing is its part of the requirements.

Comment: You can store that indexPath in some array and use that indexPath in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method something like that, I haven't try that. Also you can ask new question if it not work some one will help.