# Change the size of the TableViewCell when it is out of the view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I found out how to find the cells that disappeared from view ([swift determine if a certain row disappear from view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39140714/swift-determine-if-a-certain-row-disappear-from-view)
)

for this question my goal is to change the height of a cell when it disappeared from the view. Is this possible?

Comment: What's the purpose of changing an invisible cell?

Comment: it has an expanding cell that contains datepicker. If the cell disappeared the datepicker disappear also, unfortunately the size of the cell did not change.

Comment: Do you know how a table view works?  The cell will be abandoned anyway after disappearing from the view and will be recreated (not necessarily the same cell instance) when it reappears. Print the index path in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to prove it. The delegate methods like `heightForRow...` aren't called for invisible cells.

Comment: interesting, it means my goal is impossible to accomplish?

Comment: Your *goal* is supposed to indicate *no datepicker* at the moment the cell is recreated so the proper height is returned from the delegate method.

Comment: yes thats my goal

Answer (score 1):

Your `UITableViewDelegate` has a method called `tableView(_:didEndDisplaying:forRowAt:)`

I guess you can start from there!

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:).

Comment: thanks, but i already found the solution in deterrmining the cell if disapeared from view